# Using Normalisation would cause a mysql query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, normalization

I'm trying to set up a small community website where people can join and post news articles, blogs, personal stories, etc and I've created the site and most of the database tables when the issue of normalisation came up. Now I understand very little about the subject but spent the last few days looking into it and even though I understand it a little better I can still see how it may not be relevant in some cases, such as mine.

Here's the scenario - My site lets people join and post their own articles, and they can personalise their page by giving each article a category which is personal to them or their blog. So for example I might call a category Life In Britain where someone else might say Leeds Life, it's completely up to them.

So here's my MySQL table:

```
+------+--------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+
| ID   | Category           | Title                  | Article                  |
+------+--------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+
| 01   | life-in-leeds      | Title For This Article | Text for this article... |
| 02   | life-in-leeds      | Title For This Article | Text for this article... |
| 03   | business           | Title For This Article | Text for this article... |
| 04   | professional-stuff | Title For This Article | Text for this article... |
+------+--------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+
```

So some people have suggested that I have a table for categories as the data in the table above is repeated. So the tables would now be:

```
+----+--------------------+
| ID | Category           |
+----+--------------------+
| 01 | life-in-leeds      |
| 02 | business           |
| 03 | professional-stuff |
+----+--------------------+

+------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+
| ID   | Category | Title                  | Article                  |
+------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+
| 01   | 01       | Title For This Article | Text for this article... |
| 02   | 01       | Title For This Article | Text for this article... |
| 03   | 02       | Title For This Article | Text for this article... |
| 04   | 03       | Title For This Article | Text for this article... |
+------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+
```

So lets say that user_1 owns category 01 & category 02 and has 10 articles in total, 5 of which are category 01 & the other 5 are category 02. Lets say he deletes both categories so now they are both set to uncategorised this causes a problem when querying becuase even though they are both uncategorised, they both have different ID's so when searching either category, only 5 will show up. So isn't it better to leave it the way it is in the original table and then change it with php, e.g. replace $life-in-leeds with $new-category where owner == $owner_name?

Comment: I don't quite understand. When he deletes the categories, shouldn't their id be set to `NULL` (in articles table)? And then you'll have 10 records without a category and can't distinguish by their former category

Comment: That's what I'm saying @kingkero - If the record needs to be changed in the `articles` table, why have a sepperate `categories` table?

Comment: When you have your foreign keys properly set up, you won't need to change. Having sth like `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL` will automatically alter the articles table when something in categories changes. Say a user deletes a category, you only have to delete the specified row and the corresponding `category_id`s will be set to `NULL` in articles table

Comment: If you have such behavior why don't you add an entity that stores the data about user's category? BTW, normalization is really simple, there are only three rules: 1) You have to have a primary key; 2) You have to have foreign keys; 3) You must not store aggregated results in your tables.

Comment: @kingkero Oh I see, so it's all about assigning a foreign key. I've seen it mentioned in blogs but haven't looked into it further

Comment: @zaratustra Why would I want to add more columns, isn't the point of this to reduce the amount of data?  I just don't get why if you have a `articles` table that holds ALL Relevant data to the article why you need to split it up into multiple other tables

Comment: I did not offer you to add columns, I offered to add a new entity, e.g. table. You have to split your tables not to have duplicated data (as you showed us in your post) if someone renames the life-in-leeds category, you will have to make at least (based on your example) updates, If you store them in separate table you will have to make only one update operation. I recommend you to read the book [Case Method by Richard Barker](http://www.amazon.com/Case-Method-Entity-Relationship-Modelling/dp/0201416964) It is the most amazing book in the entity relationship area

Comment: OK @zaratustra, but isn't any table going to have duplicated data even if you split it to 3rd or 4th NF? I mean if a user had 100 articles & you created a table like `users_articles`, that table would still have 100 rows showing the users id number - I'm really trying to understand this but I just think that 1 table per set of information makes much more sense

Comment: The more NFs you use the more tables you have. Most developers normalize their databases up to 3-th NF. For your case yes, the `users_articles` table will have 100 rows for one user but in this table you can add articles of other users and when you need to get all article of one user you can type `SELECT * FROM users_articles WHERE user_id = <DESIRED_USER_ID>` it is really powerful

Comment: Yes but with that being said, why can't you just use the same query on the `articles` table which contains all the articles written by other users anyway, i.e. `SELECT * FROM uarticles WHERE author = <DESIRED_USER_ID>`? Then you don't have to `JOIN` any other tables on as all of the data is in the `articles` table to begin with

Comment: You should not allow deleting categories that has articles. With foreign keys you can automate this by having MySQL throw an error (default), cascade (delete all articles related) or set null. With the last one you are able to find uncategorized by searcing which ones have category which `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

**Normalization does not mean "replace text with id numbers".**

We have things like First Normal Form (1NF), Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF), and Sixth Normal Form (6NF). We don't have anything like "I've replaced text with id numbers" normal form. That's not an accident.

Look at [this example from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). It starts with this table, which is in 2NF. A candidate key is {Tournament, Year}.

```
Tournament Winners 

Tournament             Year    Winner           Winner Date of Birth
--
Indiana Invitational   1998    Al Fredrickson   21 July 1975
Cleveland Open         1999    Bob Albertson    28 September 1968
Des Moines Masters     1999    Al Fredrickson   21 July 1975
Indiana Invitational   1999    Chip Masterson   14 March 1977
```

The article shows this decomposition, which aims to remove the transitive dependency `Winner->Winner Date of Birth`.

```
Tournament Winners 

Tournament            Year   Winner
--
Indiana Invitational  1998   Al Fredrickson
Cleveland Open        1999   Bob Albertson
Des Moines Masters    1999   Al Fredrickson
Indiana Invitational  1999   Chip Masterson

Winner Dates of Birth 

Winner          Date of Birth
--
Chip Masterson  14 March 1977
Al Fredrickson  21 July 1975
Bob Albertson   28 September 1968
```

Those two tables are now in at least 5NF, right? Here's the important part.

- The original table had four columns.
- Neither of the final tables has four columns.

Why is that important? Removing a dependency *always* reduces the number of columns in the table you start with.

If whatever you're doing doesn't reduce the number of columns in the table you start with, it's not normalization. It might be useful. It might be wise. But it's not normalization.

Your table started with four columns, and it ended with four columns. It started with one column that identified the category of an article, and it ended with one column that identified the category of an article. The normal form of the table you started with and the table you ended with are the same. As far as normalization is concerned, your change did nothing.

Having said that, normalization isn't the only thing you have to consider when you design databases. You could increase data integrity by adding a table like this.

```
Categories

Category
--
life-in-leeds
business
professional-stuff
```

Then set a foreign key from articles.category to categories.category. Now your database can reject misspelled categories. On the other hand, you now have to have a special procedure for adding new categories to the database.